# Determining Forgotten Password while still logged in

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, passwords

I am still logged on to my win 8 laptop but i forgot my password...help? I know that for the most part i would have to reset it or something but I just want to retrieve it. Is that possible? Help! Urgent! I have a paper due and I don't want to shut down! or hibernate or log off!

Comment: Are you using an account connected to Microsoft or a local account for your laptop?

Comment: Could you explain why exactly resetting password is not a solution for you? In the situation you have described resetting the password is the most logical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are logged in with a local account with administrator rights.

Start command prompt (in case you don't know how to start command prompt, press Windows Key + R to bring up a "Run" menu, type `cmd` and click OK).

Type the command `net user "<user_name>" <new_password>`; replace  with your user name and  with ... er... something you can remember.  Press Enter and it is done.

Comment: Nice answer, but seems more a security issue than a solution that MS has made :D

Comment: True... My original thought before doing research was, shouldn't it be impossible otherwise it poses a security flaw?  Later I found that the command need to be executed by user with administrator rights - lessening the issue by a bit maybe?

Comment: Yes, and often (not always!) admins are careful.